# MySQL data on ramdisk partition

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ramdisk, docker

I'm using Docker with Ubuntu for my CI and development environment. I would like to put the database on a ramdisk partition to speed up the builds, since I have to reload my fixtures a lot, so data persistence isn't an issue here.

Is that possible? 
What steps I should add to my Docker file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is excerpt from [my post in the DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48733/877)

```
RAMDISK_SIZE=32g
service mysql stop
mkdir /var/tmpfs
echo "none   /var/tmpfs  tmpfs  defaults,size=${RAMDISK_SIZE} 1 2" >> /etc/fstab
mount -t tmpfs -o size=${RAMDISK_SIZE} none /var/tmpfs
cp -R /var/lib/mysql/* /var/tmpfs
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_old
ln -s /var/tmpfs /var/lib/mysql
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/tmpfs
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
service mysql start
```

I hope you can apply it to Ubuntu

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I used something along this lines, but I discovered that my DB data is so small (~10Mb) that I obtained no performance inprovement: all the DB files where always already on cache, hence already on RAM.